# PHP Force Download For RTMP

Tags: php, download, rtmp

I'm trying to download rtmp stream with php but every time it returns empty file. Is there any method to this aim?

```
$file_url = 'rtmp://16.somestream/live';
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) ."\""); 
readfile($file_url);
```

Comment: According to [the list of supported URI protocols and wrappers](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php), `rtmp://` is unsupported by filesystem functions like `readfile`, `fopen`, etc. So I'd be surprised if you're not getting any warnings, let alone some kind of response.

Comment: @Bytewave is there any way to download rtmp with converting it to another file type such as mp4.